# Can't install packages without installing IBus and removing Ubuntu-desktop

Tags: unity, apt, package-management, ibus

I have Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS. So I was trying to solve the issue where IntelliJ complains about IBus not being updated to 1.5.11. So I followed the instructions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/735189/ibus-1-5-11-on-ubuntu/735381#735381) and now I can't install any packages without removing unity. `apt-get` tells me to run `sudo apt-get install -f` but it gives me this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libopencc1 libpyzy-1.0-0 python-ibus python-support
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-settings-daemon
  libgoa-backend-1.0-1
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gir1.2-ibus-1.0 ibus ibus-pinyin ibus-table ubuntu-desktop
  unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon
  webaccounts-extension-common xul-ext-webaccounts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-settings-daemon
  libgoa-backend-1.0-1
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 9 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 2,351 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,876 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

It looks like apt-get wants me to uninstall unity and install gnome instead, which I do not want to do. How do I get around this? I sometimes type in other languages so disabling IBus is not an option. I am open to installing something like `scim` but I cant install anything without doing this removal process.

If I go through with this, can I install unity/ubuntu desktop back without breaking my installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ibus` depends on `ubuntu-desktop` and `unity-control-center`. Your installation attempt might break it that causes Ubuntu requires to remove `ubuntu-desktop` and `unity-control-center`. If you try to remove `sudo apt-get remove ibus`, it will also tell:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED
ibus ibus-table ubuntu-desktop unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon
```

And if you check the dependencies list of `ibus`, you will see them

```
$ apt-cache rdepends ibus
ibus
Reverse Depends:
  ibus-mozc
    ibus:i386
  unity-settings-daemon
    ibus:i386
  ubuntu-gnome-desktop
    ibus:i386
  ibus-tegaki
    ibus:i386
  ibus-skk
    ibus:i386
  ibus-rime
    ibus:i386
  ibus-pinyin
    ibus:i386
  indicator-keyboard
  ibus-libthai
    ibus:i386
  ibus-kkc
    ibus:i386
  ibus-input-pad
    ibus:i386
  ibus-cangjie
    ibus:i386
  ibus-array
    ibus:i386
  gnome-control-center
    ibus:i386
  unity-settings-daemon
    ibus:i386
  unity-control-center
    ibus:i386
  unity-control-center
    ibus:i386
  ubuntu-desktop
    ibus:i386
  ibus-hangul
    ibus:i386
  ibus-unikey
    ibus:i386
  ibus-table
    ibus:i386
  ibus-m17n
    ibus:i386
  ibus-dbg
    ibus:i386
  ibus-anthy
    ibus:i386
  ibus-chewing
    ibus:i386
  gnome-settings-daemon
    ibus:i386
```

Now you have no other choice except removing them and get back then by launching the command to reinstall `unity`:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

I make sure it will get back normal then.